# Adding a text to an image in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Is there the most popular way of adding a text on an image in Python? I found a few completely different approaches, this seems to be best, but it doesn't work:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw 
img = Image.open("/full_path/1.jpg")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-C.ttf", 16)
draw.text((0, 0),"Sample Text",(255,255,255),font=font)
img.save('/full_path/sample-out.jpg')
```

After its running, the picture still doesn't have a text on it.

Comment: Try putting the text somewhere else.  IIRC, the PIL coordinate system puts (0,0) at the top left.  If `draw.text()` takes a coordinate for the baseline of the text, you're drawing outside the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

img=Image.open("pathToImage")

font = ImageFont.truetype("pathToFont",10)

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0),"This is a test",(255,255,0),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("a_test.png")
```